# Javascript objects to contain functions / scope issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a decent sized app with a couple of areas which have quite a bit of javascript, some of these forms are quite long, with parts of them using ajax.

I am using objects to try and contain the functions but I just wonder;

- In a couple of instances I can't use `this.` but must use the object name. This happens like in the `clearButton` setup. I also have the issue happen if I pass any function on this object to use as a call back (like ajax success), so it mean anything in my `ajaxSuccessCallBack` function I have use `OptionsForm` and can't use `this`
- It feels like I am reinventing the wheel here, would using angular be better suited for this (or something else), or can I improve my current objects? Often I am building html in the page but for that I use HTML stored in `<script type=text/html` areas.

Here is some of the code I am using. jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/vKXzL/1/

HTML

```
<form class="options" action="" method="post">
    <input name="name" value="" />
    <input name="email" type="email" value="" />
    <select name="options"></select>
    <button name="clear_name">Reset</button>
    <button name="submit" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Javascript

```
var OptionsForm = {
    init: function() {
        this.declarations();
        this.bindings();
    },
    declarations: function() {
        this.form = $('form.options');
        this.nameField = this.form.find('input[name=name]');
        this.emailField = this.form.find('input[name=email]');
        this.optionsField = this.form.find('select[name=options]');
        this.clearButton = this.form.find('button[name=clear_name]');
        this.submitButton = this.form.find('button[name=submit]');

    },
    bindings: function() {
        this.clearButton.on('click', function(e) { 
            e.preventDefault(); 
            OptionsForm.clearName(); 
        });
    },
    clearName: function(e) {
        this.nameField.val('');    
    },
    ajaxSuccessCallBack: function(response) {
      // anything here I have to use OptionsForm   
    },
    populateOptions: function(options) {
        // clear the field

        // loop the options and add to list
    }
};
OptionsForm.init();
```

Answer (score 2):

This is actually a classic example of a weird part of Javascript. What happens in your `clearButton` function is a result of `this` being locally assigned to the callback function. A common way of avoiding this is to assign `this` to another variable before the callback so you get the following:

```
bindings: function() {
    var that = this;
    this.clearButton.on('click', function(e) { 
        e.preventDefault(); 
        that.clearName(); 
    });
}
```

The same will apply to the ajaxSuccessCallback.

Comment: This isn't a weird part of javascript, it is context/scope assignment. jQuery contextually assigns `this` to the DOM element that was clicked using `.apply` or `.call`. Saying that, this solution will work so +1

Comment: Thanks, I will make use of `that`. It just feels like the code has a lot going on for very little

Answer (score 1):

It is because of the execution context of the method, one possible solution is to use [Function.bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)/[$.proxy()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) like

```
this.clearButton.on('click', $.proxy(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    OptionsForm.clearName();
}, this));
```

and instead of just passing `ajaxSuccessCallBack`, pass `$.proxy(this.ajaxSuccessCallBack, this)`

Answer (score 0):

Yes these are classic problems with classic solutions. In your button case it's all about execution context: exactly what does "this" mean when that "click" gets fired.

A framework such as jQuery, Dojo or angularJS will help. I'd recommend using a framework because they help with larger problems such as the organisation of your app's code as well as addressing these point problems.

Comment: I am already using jQuery - so does that mean I am doing it wrong? Explain how using jQuery could help here.

Comment: It's such a common problem that teh frameworks provide a nice wrapper, in the case of Dojo it's lang.hitch() in the case of jQuery its proxy() http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/

Answer (score -1):

You are doing it absolutely correct.

The value of `this` in JavaScript depends on the current context of the execution rather the function context.

For example:

```
var showContext = function() {
    console.log(this); // will log window
}
```

[image: global context]

`showContext()` is same as `window.showContext()`, as the current context is `window` and the function `showContext` is defined to the window.

Let's consider another example:
    var obj = { name : 'stackoverflow'};
    obj.showContext = function() {
        console.log(this.name);
    }

```
var name = 'stackexchange';
var fun = obj.showContext;

obj.showContext(); // stackoverflow    
fun(); //stackexchange
```

[image: this in different context]

When a `function` is passed as a `callback` to a `event`, the `context` (or `this`) of the `function` is the `element` to which the `event` is attached,  when executed by the `event`.

Your code is absolutely fine. But you might feel it weird to use the `Object.function()` notation as in

```
bindings: function() {
    this.clearButton.on('click', function(e) { 
        e.preventDefault(); 
        OptionsForm.clearName(); 
    });
}
```

You can modify the function as

```
bindings: function() {
    var _this = this;
    this.clearButton.on('click', function(e) { 
        e.preventDefault(); 
        _this.clearName(); 
    });
}
```

I have updated the fiddle as per the above code, please find it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/sarbbottam/vKXzL/2/)

Comment: You shouldn't use code spans (`like this`) for highlighting stuff (if you have to, use bold/italic).